# Assembly files in obj-m list when building kernel modules

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, make, assembly

I'm trying to build kexec as a module, but I'm running into a weird problem.  My obj-m is:

```
obj-m += kexec.o machine_kexec.o relocate_kernel.o
```

When I run the makefile, it complains that there's "no rule to make target relocate_kernel.c, needed by relocate_kernel.o"

How should I be telling it to include the assembly file?  I've looked in the kernel Makefile, and while I'm not very good with them, it DOES appear that there's a rule for .S > .o.  Am I wrong about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As always, RTFM.  Answering this and leaving it up to help others that may come across this.  Per the Linux documentation project, I was using obj-m wrong:

> Sometimes it makes sense to divide a kernel module between several source files.
>   Here's an example of such a kernel module.
>
> [ Source files ... ]
>
> And finally, the makefile:
>
> Example 2-10. Makefile
>
> obj-m += hello-1.o
>   obj-m += hello-2.o
>   obj-m += hello-3.o
>   obj-m += hello-4.o
>   obj-m += hello-5.o
>   obj-m += startstop.o
>   startstop-objs := start.o stop.o
>
> all:
>     make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
>
> clean:
>     make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

[Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide:  2.7. Modules Spanning Multiple Files](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x351.html)

So, my Makefile should have read:

```
obj-m += kexecmod.o
kexecmod-objs := kexec.o machine_kexec.o relocate_kernel.o
```

Which compiled relocate_kernel.S into relocate_kernel.o

(To anyone stumbling across this trying to compile kexec as a module, I still haven't found all the dependencies, but this is a start.)